# Is there a way to testfor players at multiple coordinates with one command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For example, I want to test for players on a specific row of z and y (only x changes)

```
/testfor @a[149,30,298,1] 
/testfor @a[148,30,298,1] 
/testfor @a[147,30,298,1] 
/testfor @a[146,30,298,1] 
/testfor @a[145,30,298,1]
```

and so on...

is there a way to put this into one command instead of placing many commandblocks for each one?

Comment: Pretty sure that you can't format your target selector using just numbers like you used to be able to, but now have to include the `x=` part for each axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a specific radius in the testfor command like this:
`testfor @a[x=...,y=...,z=...,r=<radius>]`.

You can also test for players in a box: `testfor @a[x=10,y=10,z=10,dx=5,dy=5,dz=5]`
 will select a box from coordinates [10, 10, 10] to [15, 15, 15].

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute if entity @a[x=...,y=...,z=...,distance=..<radius>]`